# Android Google Maps API String inside the Marker Icon

Tags: android, string, google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers

Is there a way I can  put a value of a String inside the `Marker`'s icon on Google Maps API 2.0?
Like this image

[image: this img]

in a simple way. Somewhat like this:

```
   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(POSITION)
                    .title("Your title")
                    .icon(HERE PUT MY VAR STRING)
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Google Maps API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) and customize you markers using bubble icons:

```
IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Your text"))).
    position(new LatLng(-33.8696, 151.2094)).
    anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
```

Comment: Thanks ! Awesome solution !

Answer (score 4):

You can custom icon with your text:

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

// paint defines the text color, stroke width and size
Paint color = new Paint();
color.setTextSize(35);
color.setColor(Color.BLACK);

// modify canvas
canvas.drawText(YOUR_STRING, 30, 40, color);

// add marker to Map
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(USER_POSITION)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers didn't work for me , got an example from [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) that solved the issue: 
[How to replace marker image with textview in google maps api for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719278/how-to-replace-marker-image-with-textview-in-google-maps-api-for-android/37730323#37730323)