# How to replace marker image with textview in google maps api for android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have looked everywhere , yet i can not find an answer .
I want to display the marker info right away, without the need to click on it in order to see the info . 
I tried all answers here: [Android Google Maps API String inside the Marker Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626354/android-google-maps-api-string-inside-the-marker-icon/37628149#37628149) 
with no success and no errors either

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626354/android-google-maps-api-string-inside-the-marker-icon/37628149#37628149

Comment: How many markers are there? Only one or more than one?

Comment: Paresh Mayani : yes , unknown amount since it is a results of near by establishments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the example provided at: [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) 
[specifically this github demo code class](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/IconGeneratorDemoActivity.java)

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.maps.android.utils.demo;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.ui.IconGenerator;

import static android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD;
import static android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC;
import static android.text.Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE;

public class IconGeneratorDemoActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

    @Override
    protected void startDemo() {
        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-33.8696, 151.2094), 10));

        IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
        addIcon(iconFactory, "Default", new LatLng(-33.8696, 151.2094));

        iconFactory.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        addIcon(iconFactory, "Custom color", new LatLng(-33.9360, 151.2070));

        iconFactory.setRotation(90);
        iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_RED);
        addIcon(iconFactory, "Rotated 90 degrees", new LatLng(-33.8858, 151.096));

        iconFactory.setContentRotation(-90);
        iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_PURPLE);
        addIcon(iconFactory, "Rotate=90, ContentRotate=-90", new LatLng(-33.9992, 151.098));

        iconFactory.setRotation(0);
        iconFactory.setContentRotation(90);
        iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN);
        addIcon(iconFactory, "ContentRotate=90", new LatLng(-33.7677, 151.244));

        iconFactory.setRotation(0);
        iconFactory.setContentRotation(0);
        iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_ORANGE);
        addIcon(iconFactory, makeCharSequence(), new LatLng(-33.77720, 151.12412));
    }

    private void addIcon(IconGenerator iconFactory, CharSequence text, LatLng position) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
                icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(text))).
                position(position).
                anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());

        getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    private CharSequence makeCharSequence() {
        String prefix = "Mixing ";
        String suffix = "different fonts";
        String sequence = prefix + suffix;
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
        ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(ITALIC), 0, prefix.length(), SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(BOLD), prefix.length(), sequence.length(), SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return ssb;
    }
}
```