# How to add letters to the google map standard marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add letter in default marker of Google map. It should look like

[image: this.]

Comment: Post some code, show what you have done

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

Comment: show what you tried... don't paste requirements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map Markers with text in Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837510/map-markers-with-text-in-google-maps-android-api-v2)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626354/android-google-maps-api-string-inside-the-marker-icon/37628149#37628149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method takes a drawable from your resources, draws some text on top of it(inside the marker) and returns the new drawable. All you need to do is give it the resource id of your bubble, and the text you want on top. Then you can pass the returned drawable wherever you want it.

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTextSize(20); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

Note:

To preserver density you need this constructor

```
BitmapDrawable (Resources res, Bitmap bitmap)
```

So, keeping your context, last return should be something like

```
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);
```

This prevent an undesired resized drawable.

Comment: Create custom marker icon is the only way to add a some text?

Comment: 'BitmapDrawable(android.graphics.Bitmap)' is deprecated as of API 16: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)